# Extract quoted values from SQL insert query string

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am trying to use split to split a string. But I am stuck coming up with a regexp to suit my needs. The string will look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO  VALUES ('Cardinal','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger',4006,'Norway');
```

I need to be able to retrieve all the values between the `''`. The key is keeping strings intact. So `Tom B. Erichsen` should be one string and not seperated into `Tom`, `B.`, `Erichsen`.

The other thing is that integers are not going to be surrounded by `''`.

Can anyone give me a suggestions on how I can use split or another way to parse this information?

Comment: This is not a regular language so regular expressions are the wrong way to try to solve it. It should be quite easy to walk through the string, parsing out the different components.

Comment: @DavidConrad: you must make the difference between the theorical meaning of `regular expressions` and the sense the actual implementations give to this term.

Comment: While it's true that most implementations provide things beyond textbook regular expressions, I think that when people start trying to parse irregular things with regexes they get into trouble. Take this example: Can quoted strings contain escaped single quotes? Will they ever contain commas? Parsing this with a finite state machine is easy; using a regex will leave you with far more than just two problems.

Comment: @DavidConrad: This is legends. The reality is when people studies a language, the regex part is always like a spare dick at a wedding. Finding escaped quotes inside quotes is easy. Checking if there are commas too. The actual implementation allows a wide flexibility.

Comment: Fine, let's see your regex to parse this: `INSERT INTO VALUES ('Don't blink''\\'', ''Can, ''you\, tell'');', 'where each begins, ', 'and ends?');`

Comment: @DavidConrad: Why not, I'm agree to do that if you provide a valid SQL query.

Comment: I believe that is valid SQL-92.

Comment: @DavidConrad I think you need to double the apostrophe in `Don't`.

Comment: `'(?>[^\\']++|''|\\\\|\\.)*'` (with the correction suggested by David Wallace)

Comment: Note that you only need to deal with even numbers of quotes or backslashes to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it pieces.

It's not valid SQL (no table), but I'm sure it's just an example.

I'd start by pulling the substring out from the parentheses.

Then I'd split that assuming comma-separated values.

Then I'd deal with each value.

Not trivial, and not one step.

It might be that a grammar and lexer/parser for SQL INSERT would be better.  Try looking at ANTLR.

Comment: There could be commas inside strings, though. I wouldn't bother with ANTLR. A simple FSM would do fine.

Answer (score 0):

This code works on the example you provided ..

```
 String query = "INSERT INTO  VALUES ('Cardinal','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger',4006,'Norway');";
    String inside = query.substring(query.indexOf("(")+1, query.indexOf(")"));
    String[] elements = inside.split(",");
    for (String string : elements) {
        if(string.startsWith("'")){
            string = string.substring(1,string.length()-1);
        }
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```